# imaplib proxy authentication

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I'm having some trouble with imap. 
What I'm trying to do is write a script that will connect to our voicemail server using imap and download all messages.
I've been able to log in with individual accounts, but when I try to use "proxyauth" to log in as an administrator and proxy into another subscriber's mailbox I get the following error:

"imaplib.error: PROXYAUTH command error: BAD ['Unrecognized command']"

And here's the code I'm using:

```
c = imaplib.IMAP4("x.x.x.x")
c.login_cram_md5("admin", "******")
c.proxyauth("7001")

type, data = c.select()

try:
    c.select('INBOX', readonly=True)

    for i in c.search(None, 'All')[1][0].split():
        print "\n===================================="
        print "Reading Message: " + str(i) + "..."
        print "====================================\n"
        typ, msg_data = c.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                print email.message_from_string(str(msg_data[0][1]))

finally:
    try:
        c.close()
    except:
        pass
c.logout()
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Proxyauth is an extension, and your server doesn't support it?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make sure?

Comment: What's your server vendor?  I've not actually seen any commonly used IMAP server that supports PROXYAUTH.

Answer (score 1):

PROXYAUTH was an old Netscape IMAP server extension.

See if your server supports AUTHENTICATION PLAIN.  Telnet on port 143, login, and issue the CAPABILITY command, and look for AUTH=PLAIN in the response.  For example:

```
telnet <server> 143
* OK IMAP Server ready
1 login user password
1 OK completed
1 capability
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4REV1 ACL NAMESPACE UIDPLUS IDLE LITERAL+ QUOTA ID MULTIAPPEND LISTEXT CHILDREN BINARY LOGIN-REFERRALS UNSELECT STARTTLS AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=MSN AUTH=NTLM
```

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4959 for details on AUTHENTICATION PLAIN.

-Rick

Answer (score 0):

The IMAP server is telling you that it does not recognize the `PROXYAUTH` command. There is no such command in standard IMAP.

Correct way to "proxy authenticate" as someone else depends on your particular IMAP server implementation; you will have to look up its documentation. Chances are that it's implemented via the `AUTHENTICATE` command.

Comment: Thanks fro the tip. The particular server I'm working on is an Avaya CMM voicemail server which uses Courier as it's IMAP/POP3 server. I'll try to dig a little deeper for a way to make this work.